# Make Excel formula yield `blank` as an ISBLANK() = TRUE

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Make Excel formula yield `blank` as an ISBLANK() = TRUE

I found couple poster asking about what are the differences between `""` and simply (blank), but now how do make formula return blank?

Example:

```
=IF(TRUE,blank,"1")
```

I dont' have exact formula that I am trying to make, so for argument sake lets make formmula abote return blank on `TRUE`.

The thing that matters to me about this is that `""` is text so even thoough there is not usefull infomration in this string this `ISTEXT("")` is still `TRUE`

Comment: Why not just test for text? Or for `" "` or even use `if(countblank(A1)=1,`. You can't return nothing in excel.

Comment: Actually that does sound like next best thing

Comment: The presence of this placeholder, which forces the cell to be evaluated and appear as blank, means that the cell temporarily assumes the (text) format of the placeholder.  You can't put something in a cell to act as "empty" and not have something there (you can't eat your cake and have it, too).  You would need something like VBA to actually delete all content from the cell for it to be truly empty.  If ISTEXT is a problem for your application, use a different test.  There are a number of quirks and limitations in Excel that you just need to adjust for.

Comment: @fixer1234 I'd post that as an answer instead of a comment if I were you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The presence of the "" placeholder, which forces the cell to be evaluated and appear as blank, means that the cell temporarily assumes the (text) format of the placeholder. You can't put something in a cell to act as "empty" and not have something there (you can't eat your cake and have it, too). You would need something like VBA to actually delete all content from the cell for it to be truly empty. If ISTEXT is a problem for your application, use a different test or add an ISBLANK test to determine whether a "" is what is being detected as text. There are a number of quirks and limitations in Excel that you just need to adjust for.

Comment: Actually [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16929788/how-to-make-a-vba-custom-function-return-nothing-not-0-not-a-blank-string-bu) was concluded that even VBA will not help

Comment: That reference talks about using a macro to delete a cell.  That's what I was referring to.